# Calculating pages in PDF based on product count

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, math

I'm creating a web app that converts a html product catalogue into a PDF. I'm trying to calculate the number of pages based on the quantity of products, passing the function the product total and returning a integer for the page count.

The product count changes on different pages due to banners being displayed.

- First page can hold 8 products
- Last page can hold 12 products
- Last page is always present if atleast 2 pages in total
- Middle pages can hold 14 products
- Middle pages present for every set of 2x pages excluding the first and last page
- If there's an odd number of pages then the second last page will hold 16 products

To give a more visual example of the catalogues page counts:

```
1 page: [8]  
2 pages: [8][12]  
3 pages: [8][16][12]  
4 pages: [8][14][14][12]  
5 pages: [8][14][14][16][12]  
6 pages: [8][14][14][14][14][12]
```

I just can't wrap my head around this, my math and algorithm skills are not up to scratch. If anyone can shed some light on the direction I should head, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: "my math and algorithm skills are not up to scratch" -> I bet they are. You've accurately describe the rules, which is the hardest part. Now take some time with pen and paper explaining to someone (or a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)) how you would paginate various numbers of products - 10, 20, 40, 100, and so on. Be completely explicit about what you're doing. Write down what you're doing. Translate that into code. Done.

Comment: Thanks @AakashM for the kind response. You're probably right, I'm likely just having a mental block. I'll take your advice and try working through this step by step.

Answer (score 2):

Logically, you would place the first page first, then last page, then check for an  odd number total and then add middles.

```
def ass(num):
    #Check for negative number
    if num <= 0: return
    #This list will be returned, start with 8, since it always has 8
    ret = [8]

    #If only on number, then return
    if num == 1: return ret
    #add 14s in the middle; even need total-2, odd number needs total-3
    to_add = num - 2 if num % 2 == 0 else num - 3

    for i in range(to_add):
        ret.append(14)

    #check for second to last if odd, we need 16 appended
    if num % 2 != 0:
        ret.append(16)
    #Final 12
    ret.append(12)

    return ret
```

Comment: I should say this will return a list of numbers such as `[8, 14, 14, 12]` or something like that

Comment: Thanks  for the response. This doesn't seem to quite work, it's looping through the number range and creating pages. For example if I feed it 8(which should return one page of [8]) it is returning [8, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 12]. Thanks for the response mate, I'll see if I can play with it, to make it work for my use case.